# Advise:: Does Laravel open multiple db connections on each user session?

Tags: node.js, laravel

I am communicating with a client who needs an app and backend for their company, they are a small ISP and they need a backend to monitor user usage and also an app.

So the IT Spec document that was submitted by a third party suggests using NodeJS as backend since its a single thread framework, no multiple db connections , I am used to Laravel for backend dev as so far there hasn't been any issues.

So I wanted some advise if Laravel or Node will be a better solution for this.

Comment: Laravel will open a single DB connection for a single DB configuration per request

Comment: Does that mean that, if I have 50 000 clients connected via api, there are 50 000 open db connections for the api http connections ?

Does that mean that Node opens one db connection and the 50 000 connections use the same connection state and process http requests ?

Comment: If you have 50 000 concurrent clients all making requests that require a database connection then you will have 50 000 database connections. For Nodejs you have options: You can either open a connection when you need it during a request or open connection(s) when the server starts. Typically people do the latter. Problem with PHP is it does not run its own server

Comment: Thanks for the info, so in this case then the best solution is to implement Node for the backend to accommodate the number of connections ??

Comment: nodejs does reuse the same connection yes (if configured that way), but that also means that connection gets tied up when someone is using it meaning that when connections in the pool run out then either new connections are made or client connections get dropped. Having 50 000 concurrent users is a challange on its own and it's not as simple as "if I use X technology all my problems go away". If you are in the fortunate position to have too many users then you might consider backend and database replicas to alleviate some of the load.